# How to call a function in template which is defined in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am extremely newbie to Django, Sorry in the advance for asking the wrong question.

I want to create a function to sum the values of a column and call it on my template in Django.

Model:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    cost_price = models.IntegerField()
    selling_price = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        amount = Invoice.objects.aggregate(Sum('selling_price'))
        return amount
```

I created this get_total function to sum of the values of *selling_price* column.

Template Code:

```
    {% for item in query_result %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.product_name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.cost_price}}</td>
            <td>{{item.selling_price}}</td>
            {{item.get_total}}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Here's the problem, after passing the data, whenever I call this function, the data is shown multiple times in the template.

Here's the output.
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VBtr.jpg)

I know it's quite silly, but I am unable to figure it out.

Help, Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly `annotate` the `aggregation`, for example:

```
Invoice.objects.aggregate(amount = Sum('selling_price'))
```

The resulting dictionary will have a key called `amount`. If no such alias were specified, it would be the rather long `selling_price__sum`

Since it returns a dict, you can get the value through:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        amount = Invoice.objects.aggregate(amount = Sum('selling_price'))['amount']
        return amount

# template
{{ item.get_total }} would only get amount value out, not dict
```

BTW:

> Adding **extra manager methods** is the preferred way to add **“table-level”**
> functionality to your models. (For “row-level” functionality – i.e.,
> functions that act on a single instance of a model object

Aggregation is a table level function, since it calculate the sum of multiple objects,  which is better defined as **[`manager method`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)** instead at model instance level.

```
class InvoiceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_total(self):
        return self.aggregate(amount = Sum('selling_price'))['amount']

class Invoice(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    cost_price = models.IntegerField()
    selling_price = models.IntegerField()
    # customized manager
    objects=InvoiceManager()
```

#### Views

```
def your_view(request):
    ...
    context = {
       'query_result': Invoice.objects.all()
       'amount': Invoice.objects.get_total()
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Minglyu. 
I tried this approach, Invoice.objects.aggregate(amount = Sum('selling_price'))
but still, It is showing the sum of values, multiple times in the template.

Comment: @MayankValechha Yeah, because it is in a for loop

Comment: Yes, I got that! But any other way of doing it, I mean without using Custom Manager? Can't we create any sorta method, which will directly get called from the Template outside of the loop?

Comment: @MayankValechha As I suggested, you better use the second approach, also you could try `query_set.0.get_total`, and put it outside the for loop, `query_set.0` means `first item`,  every item in the queryset will get exactly the same result for `get_total`, it's not a good practice！

Comment: The `calculation` and business logic should performed in the `views` and `models`, `Template`'s major task should focus on presentation, you can pass the value from the  view context, and use it in the template

Comment: Thank you, man! Now I got your point, I am gonna use the custom manager approach. Thank you so much! You helped me a lot btw this is the first question which I asked on Stackoverflow. ;)

Comment: glad it helps! happy coding